# How to filter based on IPv6 addresses assigned to an interface

Tags: linux, iptables, ipv6

In my setup i get a dynamic IPv6 prefix assigned from my router via SLAAC. I would like to block all traffic on my machine which does not originate from this dynamic prefix.

For this I need to filter out all packets with a source address which is not in my dynamically assigned prefix.

Is there a iptables rule which can do this? Or do I need to write a custom script for this?

Comment: This probably won't work as most traffic on the lan will be on the link-local address

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this in iptables.

The best way I can think of to achieve this is to assign all the hosts on your network a [ULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) address, and use those addresses for all your local traffic. Then you can block incoming connections from all GUA addresses without compromising your LAN traffic.